# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPPasswordMGr'

Tags: python

I am trying to post a message on twitter with my account, but I kept getting this error (the one in the title) and I am not sure why I am getting this error, please help me.

```
import urllib.request
import time
def send_to_twitter():
    msg = "I am a message that will be sent to Twitter!"
    password_manager = urllib.HTTPPasswordMGr()
    password_manager.add_password("Twitter API",
                                  "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet", "My ID", "My pass")
    authhandler = urllib.HTTPBasicAuthHandler
    http_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
    page_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(http_handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(page_opener)
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode( {'status': msg} )
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json", params)
    resp.read()
on = 1
loop = 0
while on == 1:
        print("Do you wish to send message?")
        print("Option: (Y/N)")
        ans = input()
        while ans == ("Y") or ans ==("y"):
                print("Processing...")
                time.sleep(1)
                send_to_twitter()
        else:
                price = 999.99
                while price > 999.89:
                        send_to_twitter()
                        break
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `.request`:

```
password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgr()
```

Same with `HTTPBasicAuthHandler` and make sure you actually call it:

```
 authhandler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
```

Comment: It still says that module has no attribute "HTTPPasswordMGr" after I added in

Comment: If you used what I have in my answer and you are using python3 then it certainly does have HTTPPasswordMgr, if you are getting an error then you are doing something wrong